# If $f$ has an removable singularity at $a$, then $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Conway's complex analysis book and on page 103 he state the following theorem:

[image]

He doesn't prove the $\Rightarrow$ part and I would like to know if my attempt is true:

**Attempt:**

If $z=a$ is a removable singularity, then there is  a function $g$ analytic in $B(a;R)$, with $g(z)=f(z)$ for $0<|z-a|<R$. Therefore, we have

$$g(z)=a_0+a_1(z-a)+a_2(z-a)^2+\ldots$$

Then for $0<|z-a|<R$, we have

$$f(z)=a_0+a_1(z-a)+a_2(z-a)^2+\ldots$$

and so

$$(z-a)f(z)=(z-a)a_0+a_1(z-a)^2+a_2(z-a)^3+\ldots$$

Thus

$$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$$

My only worry is I don't know if the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum when the sum is infinite as it is in this case.

Comment: Since we have a convergent power series, that is the case. (The convergence is uniform on some neighbourhood of $a$.) But it's more elementary to just note that $f$ is bounded on $0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < r$ for some $r < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $g$ is analytic in $D(a,r)$, then observe that $\lim_{z \to a} f(z) = \lim_{z \to a} g(z) = g(a)$. So $|f|$ is bounded near $a$. So the limit must be zero.

Added:

To prove it rigorously, recall that if $h$ is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, we have:

$$\lim_{z \to a}h(z) = L \iff (\forall \epsilon)(\exists \delta)(0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |h(z) - L| < \epsilon)$$

Now we may just use the epsilon-delta definition of limit for $\lim_{z \to a}g(z) = g(a)$, and replace $g(z)$ by $f(z)$ because they are equal on $\{z: 0<|z-a|<\delta\}$ (where $\delta$ is chosen to be $<R$)

Comment: Intuitively I know that $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\lim_{z\to a}g(z)$. How can we prove this formally? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user42912 you're welcome! I added some rigour to my answer.

Comment: Thank you again, that's exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there is a  function $g$ which is defined on all of $B(a,r)$ and analytic here, with $f = g$ on $B(a,r) - \{a\}$.  Then

$$\lim\limits_{z \to a} f(z) = \lim\limits_{z \to a} g(z) = g(a) \in \mathbb{C}$$

As for why these limits are the same, we just use the fact that this limit just depends on the points near $a$, not on $a$ itself.  In general, if $U$ is an open subset of a metric space $X$, with $a \in U$, and $F$ is any function with domain $U$ (or even $U - \{a\}$, it doesn't matter), then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} F(x)$, if it exists, is independent of the value $F(a)$ (or $F(a)$ might not even be defined, it doesn't matter).

Now

$$\lim\limits_{z \to a} (z-a) = 0$$

It's always true that the limit of a product is the product of the limits, if those limits are both finite.